# Prevent applications to write to windows registry

Tags: windows, security, windows-registry, uac, security-policy

Is there a possibility for me to see uac promt every time some app trying to edit registry?
Maybe run all apps in low integrity level by default or set writing to registry to high integrity?

The reason why I want it is that my registry is blotted with records of applications, that I don't even have on my pc anymore and I really don't want any app leave their sh*t in my os without permission.

Also if there was an utility to virtualize registry edit using file near application executable that would be even better solution.

So do you, guys, have any thoughts on this?

Comment: Why is this a problem? The registry takes care of itself and usually does not require micromanagement. Are you trying to solve a specific problem, or just upset at the number of apparently leftover elements in it?

Comment: I'm just upset. I always trying to make sure my os stays as "clean" as possible. My problem with that when I trying to find some records there always 3-4 years old records of an app that is not used.

I disagree with you that registry takes care of itself, it's quite opposite in my experience. It's up to an application developer to clean application related data from registry on uninstall.

Comment: Seems like an awful idea. But if you want to break all your programs, regedit -> right click HKCU or HKLM -> permissions -> remove full control from yourself and creator owner. Realize most programs store things like "recently opened files" and "last working directory" in the registry. This cannot be set on a per-program basis, though you might be able to force it with "Run As." It will cause registry writes to straight up fail.

Comment: @AndrewDomaszek Thanks for the pointer. Didn't notice it there.

Comment: @Ramhound I'm grateful for your concern, but there was no intention to prevent system from accessing registry in any way. Only a users group.

Comment: You all may be right about awfulness of an idea and I will definitely will play with it in test environment only.

Comment: @Ramhound hm... I guess you are right. Thanks for explaining that to me. I think this question can be considered settled, since there is no way to do it. Can you post it as an answer?

Comment: The amount of information in the registry is not a problem. Not even old information about programs long removed is a problem. The only problem is if the registry is unable to quickly and efficiently retrieve the requested information. When I say the registry is able to take care of itself, I mean that even with a load of extraneous crap it is still able to quickly and efficiently return the requested information. It has been shown time and again that the potential downsides for "cleaning" your registry far outweigh the downsides of leaving it alone.